# How can I measure the distance between a raspberry pi and a moving/mobile beacon? Reducing noise in RSSI

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, kalman-filter, rssi

I would like to know the distance between a raspberry pi and a moving/mobile beacon.

Has anyone implemented a kalman filter (preferably python) or determined a better algorithm for improving distance estimates, based on Radio Signal Strength measurements in a wireless Network environment?

The algorithm would have to be recursive to work in an online environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/ArmaRssiFilter.java), there is a ARMA filter that may be selected to choose RSSI samples for distance estimates.  You can see the source code in Java here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/service/ArmaRssiFilter.java

While a Kalman filter and ARMA filter are not the same, they can both be used to similar effect.  The advantage of an ARMA filter over the Android Beacon Library's simpler running average default RSSI selection algorithm is that it tends to converge to a steady result with fewer samples when the beacon is at a steady distance.